# Нужны ли знаки препинания после закрытия кавычек в приведенных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

**Навязчивая мысль: "Надо бежать" не давала мне покоя.

Вопрос: "Как не попасться?" - вынудил меня продумать дальнейшие действия.**

Насколько мне известно, в подобных случаях после многоточий, вопросительных и восклицательных знаков, входящих в кавычки, нужно ставить тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для правильного оформления Ваших предложений есть два варианта.

**1.** Прямая речь находится внутри слов автора.

1.1. Тире после прямой речи ставится в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва слов автора (§ 136, пункт "б"):
**Навязчивая мысль: "Надо бежать" — не давала мне покоя.**

1.2.  Тире после прямой речи ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком (§ 136, пункт "в"):
**Вопрос: "Как не попасться?" — вынудил меня продумать дальнейшие действия.**

**2.** Прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена. Знаки препинания до и после слов в кавычках не нужны, т. к. их нет в словах автора (§ 136, пункт "г"):

**Навязчивая мысль "Надо бежать" не давала мне покоя.

Вопрос "Как не попасться?" вынудил меня продумать дальнейшие действия.**

[**Знаки препинания при прямой речи. § 136**](http://www.orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рассмотрела и первый пример прямой речи ("надо бежать"), и второй ("как не попасться") как несогласованные определения. Они дословно выражают авторскую мысль (или слова какого-либо лица).
Поэтому хочется их оформить как часть цитаты, написав со строчной буквы.

*Навязчивая мысль "надо бежать" не давала мне покоя.

Вопрос "как не попасться" вынудил меня продумать дальнейшие действия.*

Comment: Добрый вечер, shampar. А что, Вы что-то изменили? Простите, я не заметила.

Comment: Так и хорошо, что прошло незаметно. Основное: ссылки или комментарии к ответам  существующим делать не стоит: ответ должен быть самодостаточным.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Навязчивая мысль "надо бежать!" // не давала мне покоя.** Вариант без пауз (несогласованное определение). Читается как простое предложение.

**Навязчивая мысль: "надо бежать!"  — не давала мне покоя.**  Вариант с паузами для выделения высказывания, упрощенное оформление прямой речи.

**2) Вопрос "как не попасться?" // вынудил меня продумать дальнейшие действия.**(Несогласованное определение). Здесь выделять содержание вопроса нет необходимости. Читается как простое предложение.